# Windows 10 SSD upgrade

Tags: windows-10, ssd, installation

My neighbor indicates her Gateway SX2110G Windows 10 returns "[No boot disk has been detected or the disk has failed.](https://appuals.com/fix-no-boot-disk-detected-disk-failed/)"  Assume that the hard drive has failed and needs replacing.

It's an older machine, so I ordered an SSD and plan to install Win-10 from USB stick.  When activating, will the MS activation server recognize the configuration details (CPU serial, LAN MAC ID, etc.) and activate the fresh SSD Win-10 install?

I would like to understand the obstacles to activation, because if it is too much, then I will consider an alternative (Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

The windows activation status belongs to the mother board or a Microsoft account, you just need to install the same version of windows eg.windows 10 home then it will automatic activated when you connect to internet after install. 
take a look this link  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/windows-10-activation-after-replacing-hdd-with-ssd/1f285b64-abb3-487f-8459-5a253183f1b0